# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split'), how to remove error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When adding some fields to the page (from the client side), an error occurs: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')`. Occurs in this code snippet
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

```
module.exports = function(role) {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
            next();
        }
        try {
            const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
            if (!token) {
                return res.status(401).json({message: "Not authorized"});
            }
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
            if (decoded.role !== role) {
                return res.status(403).json({message: "No access"});
            }
            req.user = decoded;
            next();
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message); //error message here
            res.status(401).json({message: "Not authorized"});
        }
    };
}
```

Moreover, if you add it from the server side (for example, in postman), then everything works well. Where is the mistake?

Comment: That means that your `req.headers.authorization` is not a string. What is the result of a `console.log(req.headers.authorization)` inside your function?

Comment: undefined, why so, how can i fix it?

Comment: What about `req.headers`? You need to determine how to handle it when `req.headers.authorization` isn't defined or find out why and fix that.

Comment: @AndreySmith make sure you have string before using `split()`. What is the result if you add a `console.log(req.headers?.authorization)` inside your function?

Answer (score 1):

This simply means that `req.headers.authorization` value is not a string (or most likely it has the value: *undefined*. You should check first if the value is set (and that it is valid i.e a string) before calling split

`if(req.headers.authorization) {`
`const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];`
`}`

Answer (score 1):

I had got the same problem. It was happening because backend server was not getting token from client side. In other words, the client side is not sending the requested token of backend, `req.headers.authorization` was undefined.

In my case I was saving the token to local storage. therefore, in client side I wrote this code.

```
const token = '6d78tf8wef76w9e6fbla64bla64bla64bla64bla64bla64bla64bla64';
```

This part in a component:
(note: using 'tanstack query' for fetching data. Not the normal way.)

```
const { data: users = [], refetch } = useQuery(["users"], async () => {
    const res = await fetch(url, {
        headers: { 
          authorization: `bearer ${token}`
    }});
    return await res.json();
});
```

Look at the `headers`, this thing is sending token to the backend server.

For normal fetch function:

```
fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      authorization: `bearer ${token}`
}})
```

If anyone wants to see the backend code:

```
const verifyJWT = (req, res, next) => {

const authorization = req.headers.authorization;
console.log(req.headers);
if (!authorization) {
    res.status(401).send({ error: true, message: 'unauthorized access' });
}
const token = authorization.split(' ')[1];

jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, decode) => {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(401).send({ error: true, message: 'unauthorized access' })
    }
    req.decode = decode;
    next();
})
}
```